# Open Multiple files at once with Textpad 6.0

Tags: windows, text-editors

I want to highlight multiple files to open in Textpad 6 and have tabs across the top for each file.  I used to be able to do it but with new Textpad, I don't remember what I need to do.  I went into Configure - Pref - General and unchecked the command Allow Multiple Instances.

Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: After I reopened Textpad, it still didn't do what I expected. I would highlight 2 or 3 files expecting to have them open at once with tabs across the top, but only one file opened.  When I close the first file, there was a prompt to open the 2nd file. (The prompt is the window that asked what application I wanted to use to open the file.  That's where I select Textpad.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Right-click TextPad in the Start Menu (or wherever you launch it from) and select **Run as administrator**
2. Under `Prefs / General`, besides unchecking **Allow multiple instances to run**, make sure **Allow multiple files on the command line** is checked:

   [image]
3. Under `Prefs / View / Tabbed Document Selector`, make sure **At top of frame** is checked:

   [image]
4. Finally, under `Prefs / Associated Files`, make sure TextPad is associated with the file types you normally edit (additionally, you can also select **Replace Notepad** under`Prefs / General`)
5. OK your way out, then close and re-open TextPad (no need to run as admin now)
6. Now from *within* the app, open multiple files via `File / Open` and see if these open in multiple tabs
7. Close TextPad, then select and open multiple files in Windows Explorer (all types having been associated with TextPad above), and see if the app opens these in multiple tabs

Comment: @Steve S.: Since you're new here, be sure to accept the answer that best resolves your issue.